# Reverse linked list in C

Tags: c

I know that this question is already  posted in the forum, however I have a little issue that I tried to resolve and I didn't succeed

when I try this code or even code posted it the stackoverflow other threads, I always come up with a violation access error I tried this code

```
void reverse(node **headRef)
{
    node *current = *headRef, *next,*result=NULL;
    while(current)
    {
      next = current->next;
      current->next = result;
      result =current;
      current = next;
    }
    *headRef = result;
}
```

in eclipse cpp, visual studio and code bocks it always ends up with violation access and when I tried to debug the staff step by step I discovered I wierd think the cursor enters into the while loop even the current is NULL and even when I tried to substitue current by current->next the cursor still enters into the loop dispite of the fact that current->next already is NULL

```
while(current->next)
    {
      next = current->next;
      current->next = result;
      result =current;
      current = next;
    }
```

I tried to do the same staff recusively to avoid the loop however the issue persists

```
 void recursiveReverse(node **headRef) {
   node *first = *headRef;
   node *rest = first->next;
   if(rest ==NULL) return;
   recursiveReverse(&rest);
   first->next->next = first;
   first->next = NULL;
   *headRef = rest;
}
```

Here is the error from visual studio:

[image: screnshot of visual studio execution]

Comment: Well, that looks fine. So problem is probably with how list is declared, or how it is filled (it could be corrupted), or how you call the reverse functions (you could pass invalid pointer).

Comment: I would try assigning `NULL` to all pointers in declaration, and use `while` loops as `while(ptr != NULL)` just in case. I remember doing this solved a similar problem of mine back in time when I was studying linked lists.

Comment: Congratulations. You just made a screenshot of an error message.

Comment: (a) try debugging your algorithm with a known small list (say, five elements). (b) when you discover you're not initializing your node `next` pointers to NULL when they're constructed, fix it. (c) rare is the time you need a double-link indirection dereference like `first->next->next` to solve a problem; this isn't one of those times. (d) post the code that *creates* and adds new links to the list.

Comment: OK WhozCraig well I tested with this code which is working perfectly
`node *populate()
{
 node *first = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 node *second = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 node *third = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 node *fourth = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 node *fifth = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 first->data = 1;
 second->data = 2;
 third->data = 3;
 fourth->data =4;
 fifth->data =5;
 first->next = second;
 second->next = third;
 third->next = fourth;
 fourth->next = fifth;
 return first;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code little bit to resolve the error and sent the node back also. Hope this would help. The GCC compiler didn't shown any access violation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
  char data;
  struct Node* next;
} Node;

void print_list(Node* root) {
  while (root) {
    printf("%c ", root->data);
    root = root->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

Node* reverse(Node **root) {
  Node *current = *root, *next,*result=NULL;
  while(current){
    next = current->next;
    current->next = result;
    result =current;
    current = next;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  Node d = { 'd', 0 };
  Node c = { 'c', &d };
  Node b = { 'b', &c };
  Node a = { 'a', &b };

  Node* root = &a;
  print_list(root);
  root = reverse(&root);
  print_list(root);

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a b c d

d c b a
```

Comment: It works thanks to  Node* root = &a; the reference is used rather than the value thank you vineet1982

Comment: @user2050269 Kindly accept the answer so that other may also know